# What is pythonic way with SQLAchemy to update dataset?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to implement a simple flow in my utils:

1. Get `rs=Query()` from DB
2. Iterate over `rs` and send request `requests.get(rs['http'])`
3. Parse response and get `logo_url` value
4. Update `rs` dataset

```
import requests

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mssql://me:pass@server/db")

md = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)
table = sqlalchemy.Table('stations', md, autoload=True)

station = engine.execute("select * from stations")
for row in station:
    upd = table.filter_by(id=5).update(values={'STATION_LOGO_URL': 'http://test.com/img.png'})
    engine.execute(upd)
```

Is it possible to do something like this with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to do it without using [SQLAlchemy ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/). But with ORM it's simple:

```
class Station(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stations'
    ...
    station_logo_url = Column('STATION_LOGO_URL', NVARCHAR)
    ...

...

stations = session.query(Station).all()
for station in stations:
    logo_url = get_logo_url(station)
    station.station_logo_url = logo_url
session.commit()
```

Comment: What did you mean under "ORM" ?

Comment: @SpanishBoy Object-relational mapping

Comment: I got it :), but I was asking about what framework do you use for ORM instead of SQLAlchemy ORM?

Comment: I use SQLAlchemy ORM and my answer is based on this ORM